# Is ThreadLocal in ASP.NET equivalent to a per request variable?

Tags: asp.net, lifecycle, thread-local

I use a `ThreadLocal` variable in an ASP.NET `HttpHandler`. I assumed it will result in a new variable per request.

I have some strange behavior in my application. When a `ThreadLocal` variable is created and disposed in an ASP.NET page?

What happens if the same thread is used by ASP.NET later for another request? Does it result in a new `ThreadLocal` variable or the previously created value (which was used with another request) will be used?

If `ThreadLocal` variables are disposed when the thread is actually disposed, then my assumption fails with ASP.NET (since threads get back to pool and are not unique per request)

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET can and will reuse threads between requests- in fact, if memory serves it uses a thread from the normal .NET thread pool for each request.  You are probably better off using session state instead.

Comment: I simplified the problem. In fact the application is just initiated from a `HttpHandler`. Later, some reusable modules (for desktop applications) will handle the request in part of it's life-time, so the don't know about the ASP.NET session.

Comment: So you have reached an alternate solution then?

Comment: If `ThreadLocal` works the way I expected, then same modules can be shared for both asp.net and desktop applications, but I'm not sure.

Comment: A thread is only used for one request at a time, but threads are re-used after the request is complete.  So anything ThreadLocal may (but will not always) keep it's value from one request to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public class WebRequestLocal<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> _getter;
    private readonly object _id = new object();

    public WebRequestLocal(Func<T> getter)
    {
        _getter = getter;
    }


    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
            if(httpContext == null)
                throw new Exception("HttpContext unavailable.");

            if (httpContext.Items.Contains(_id))
                return (T)httpContext.Items[_id];


            return (T)(httpContext.Items[_id] = _getter());
        }
    }
}
```